# Crystal Reports: Suppress entire report including blank page when no records

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have multiple reports that are automatically printed through another program, and often times the there is no records for that specific report, but since it is automatically triggered it attempts to generate and print the report.

Using suppression formulas, all sections now appear blank and I only have a clean white page remaining (this includes all subreports, page headers, footers, etc. I have tested to ensure that each section is actually suppressed and not just blank).
However, this blank page is still being 'printed' as program printing it still views the blank page as a report.

How do I essentially suppress the entire report so that not even a blank page appears?

A little more info:

- The program printing the report generates very basic input parameters for the report, which is a link to a table in the database that is used to gather all the information for the report (basically the printing program always has data to send even if the report is blank).
- I am using crystal reports v12.

Comment: Though supress all sections a blank page is always created when you preview.. one option would be you can print a line as "No data" somewhere in design when there is no data.

Comment: I can't print a "No Data" line as I am trying not to have a page print at all. It seems as though I'll need to find a method outside of crystal that returns a "no data" value to the program prior to crystal trying to print the report.

Comment: How do you suppress an entire report? You just get a blank report. I've set up e-mail rules to delete reports that are below a certain size. Your solution is likely outside of Crystal Reports.